# "Syntax error: Bad for loop variable" when trying to run awk in a loop in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have an `awk` command which runs well on terminal: this `awk` command creates different file according to their column header.
awk command:

```
for((i=2;i<5;i++)); do 
    awk -v i=$i 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}NR==1{n=$i}{print $1,$i > n".txt"}' ${Batch}.result.txt
done
```

the same command when incorporated in a shell script shows error:

```
Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

It worked the following way. I tried with she-bang as suggested but it repeated the error.

```
for i in 2 3 4; do awk -v i=$i 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}NR==1{n=$i}{print $1,$i  n".txt"}'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think the error has anything to with your `Awk` command. I think you are running it in the POSIX bourne shell `sh` in which for-loop construct with `((` is not supported.

Run the script with shebang set to the path where `bash` is installed. Usually it is safe to do `#!/usr/bin/env bash` because `#!/usr/bin/env` searches `PATH` for `bash`, and `bash` is not always in `/bin`, particularly on non-Linux systems. For on a OpenBSD system, it's in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 7):

It is likely that the script is being interpreted by `/bin/sh` rather than by `bash` (or `ksh93` or any other shell that understands the C-like `for`-loop).

Make sure that the script has a `#!`-line saying

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the very top of the file (change to the shell and path that you want to be using), or that you run the script using the correct interpreter explicitly, for example:

```
bash ./scriptname
```

Answer (score 2):

A *three-parameter loop control expression* in ***bash*** should be specified as:

```
for (( EXP1; EXP2; EXP3 ))
```

---

But in your simple case I would just use:

```
for i in {2..4}; do ...
```

Comment: Isn't the first syntax the same as in the question? If he's using a shell that doesn't understand that, it won't understand `{2..4}` either. He needs to specify the shell properly, as in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the POSIX equivalent of your ksh93-syntax command (so would work with any modern implementation of `sh` including your `ash`-based shell like `dash` or busybox `ash`) would be:

```
i=2; while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]; do
  awk -v i="$i" '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}
    NR==1{n=$i}
    {print $1,$i > n".txt"}' < "${Batch}.result.txt"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Though here, it would make more sense to write it:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '
  NR == 1 {for (i = 2; i < 5; i++) file[i] = $i".txt"}
  {for (i = 2; i < 5; i++) print $1,$i > file[i]}' < "${Batch}.result.txt"
```